# Como pasar datos de excel a una tabla de SQLServer con visual c#?

Tags: c#, sql

Tengo el siguiente código en un botón, pero al momento de correr el programa me aparece el siguiente error:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 54. no se controlo argument exeption:

Aquí se presenta el código

```
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string conexion = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source=C:\\Users\MICUENTA\\Libraries\\Documents\\Copy.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

        OleDbConnection origen = default(OleDbConnection);
        origen = new OleDbConnection(conexion);


        OleDbCommand seleccion = default(OleDbCommand);
        seleccion = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", origen);

        OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adaptador.SelectCommand = seleccion;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adaptador.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        origen.Close();
        SqlConnection conexion_destino = new SqlConnection();
        conexion_destino.ConnectionString = ("MI BASE");
        conexion_destino.Open();
        SqlBulkCopy importar = default(SqlBulkCopy);
        importar = new SqlBulkCopy (conexion_destino);
        importar.DestinationTableName = "tbl_Volumen2";
        importar.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);
        conexion_destino.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Podrías indicar cual es la línea que te está lanzando el error?

Comment: OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            adaptador.SelectCommand = seleccion;

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adaptador.Fill(ds);

Comment: En el adaptador.Fill @frikinside,  no se si este bien mi conexion, o no se que pase.

Comment: Por lo general, ese mensaje de error se presenta por un mal string de conexión. Ej. `conexion_destino.ConnectionString = ("MI BASE");`

Comment: estare poniendo mal la ruta, o le falta algo mas a la conexion con Excel?

Comment: De eso no estoy seguro. Pero pareciera que el OleDB 4.0 no es compatible con esa versión de Excel. https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-jet-ole-db-4-0/

Answer (score 1):

He tomado como base el codigo que publicaste y he realizado algunas modificaciones.

1.- Descargue e instale el componente de acceso a datos:

[Access Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

2.- Cree una tabla en SQL:

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Prueba](
    [Col1] nvarchar NULL,
    [Col2] nvarchar NULL,
    [Col3] nvarchar NULL,
    [Col4] nvarchar NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

3.- En Excel cree un archivo llamado Copy.xls con la misma estructura que la tabla de SQL y adicione datos:

[image: Estructura de datos en Excel]

4.- En el evento OnClick del botón que tenemos para leer el archivo de Excel adicione el código que publicaste pero con algunos cambios:

```
protected void btnReadExcelFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    string conexion = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=C:\Users\SAND\Libraries\Documents\Copy.xlsx;Extended Properties=&quot;Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1&quot;";

    OleDbConnection origen =  new OleDbConnection(conexion);

    OleDbCommand seleccion = default(OleDbCommand);
    seleccion = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", origen);

    OleDbDataAdapter adaptador = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    adaptador.SelectCommand = seleccion;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adaptador.Fill(ds);
    GvParaGuardarValoresDeExcel.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GvParaGuardarValoresDeExcel.DataBind();
    origen.Close();
    SqlConnection conexion_destino = new SqlConnection();
    conexion_destino.ConnectionString = (@"Data Source=D4MW6WZ1\SAND;Initial Catalog=Test;User ID=usr_Framework;Password=usr_Framework");
    conexion_destino.Open();
    SqlBulkCopy importar = default(SqlBulkCopy);
    importar = new SqlBulkCopy(conexion_destino);
    importar.DestinationTableName = "Prueba";
    importar.WriteToServer(ds.Tables[0]);
    conexion_destino.Close();
}
```

Importante: Debes de tener los siguientes namespaces:

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

Comment: @abi Ya pudiste leer el archivo de Excel y enviar los datos a la tabla?